# Android 4.2:turning off wifi when wifi direct is enabled

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

For android 4.2 if it's required not to support concurrent connection and from the code I want to disable WIFI once wifi direct is enabled.

Would I be able to do that with a code (found in a previous question) such as this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(this.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);        //True - to enable WIFI connectivity .
                                         //False -disable WIFI connectivity.
```

Comment: I added this code wifiManager  =(WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); and I got this error java:322: incompatible types for the parameters of the "getSystemService"....What could be the reason for this error..Please excuse my inexperience with android programming

Comment: have you added permissions to use Wi-Fi in manifest file of your application?

If not then add this

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Thanks Anil, but which of the Manifest files should I add it too?... its already in the AndroidManifest file in the following path: /development/apps/Development/AndroidManifest.xml...Is this enough?

Comment: Yes...Add in that file...And let me know if you have any issues...

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still exists because I found that these permissions are already in this AndroidManifest.xml file..Is there anything else I could be missing out..
The exact code I have is as follows:
public WifiP2pService(Context context) { 
mContext = context;
---
WifiManager wifiManager  =(WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
-------
}

Comment: Hey you tried below code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Button btnWiFi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWiFi);

        btnWiFi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                WifiManager wifi =(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                if(wifi.isWifiEnabled())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "WiFi is Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                else
                {
                     AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                     builder.setTitle("Caution");
                     builder.setMessage("WiFi is Disabled."+"\n"+"Press Ok To Turn On WiFi.");
                     builder.setIcon(R.drawable.caution);
                     builder.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                         // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                             final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                             wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);


                         }
                 });

                     builder.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                         }
                 });

                     builder.show();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: Sorry I just saw this code.Thanks I'll try this. Since compilation takes some time,as far as I understand from the code is it that I can't create an instance from the WifiManager except within the onClick handler?. Or is it that I shouldn't use mContext.getSystemService and use instead getSystemService immediately...

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the following errors  http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=krxYNfhN and when I tried to only use the code that creates an instance from the wifiManager and using it to setEnabled with false I got the following errors http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=GDKNkCbM

Comment: Anyone :( ?..I wanted to also know what the importance of using the Context class....would I be able to call the following function instead of the one I previously used mWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible!

Wifi Direct only find peers, connect and share information, when WIFI connection is ON and is the same for all devices.